# Spring OAuth - Reload resourceIds and authorities of authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I just apply Spring Boot and Spring Cloud to build a microservice system. And I also apply Spring Oauth to it. Honestly, everything is perfect. Spring does a great job in it. 
In this system, I have a microservice project does the job of an OAuth server, using JDBC datasource, and I using Permission based for UserDetails authorities (1 User has several Permissions). There are several microservice project does the jobs of Resource server (expose Rest api using Jersey), access security is based on Permissions of Authentication of OAuth bearer token.

Resource Server OAuth config class is something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

       http.sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
       http.csrf().disable();

       http.authorizeRequests()                     
           .antMatchers("/restservice/object/list")
           .hasAuthority("PERMISSION_VIEW_OBJECT_LIST");

       //     ...
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) 
              throws  Exception {
        resources.resourceId("abc-resource-id")
                 .tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource()));
   }

   @Bean
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oauth2.datasource")
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
}
```

Everything is great! But I encounter 2 problems:

1. If I add a new microservice project as a new resourceId, and I append resourceId value to RESOURCE_IDS in table OAUTH_CLIENT_DETAILS of the OAuth client, all requests to Rest API of new resource service return error something like this
   {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Invalid token does not contain resource id (xyz-resource-id)"}
   This happens even when user logout and re-login to obtain new access token. It only works if I go to delete records of the Access token and Refresh token int table OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN and OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN in database.
2. If at runtime, Permission of a User is changed, the authorities of authentication is not reloaded, I see that AUTHENTICATION value of the Access Token in table OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN still contains old Authorities before Permission is changed. In this case, User must logout and re-login to obtain new Access Token with changed authorities.

So, are there any ways to fix these 2 problems.
I'm using Spring Cloud Brixton.SR4 and Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the default Spring JdbcTokenStore, then the users authentication is serialised and stored with the access/refresh token when the user authenticates and retrieves their token for the first time.

Each time the token is used to authenticate, it is this stored authentication that is loaded which is why changes to the user permissions or the addition of extra resources is not reflected in the users permissions.

In order to add in some checking on this, you can extend DefaultTokenServices and override the loadAuthentication(String accessTokenValue) method to perform your own checks once the users authentication is loaded from the token store.

This may not be the ideal way of doing this, but it is the only way we've found of doing it so far.

To override DefaultTokenServices, add the follwoing bean method to you AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter config class:

```
class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerTokenServices authorizationServerTokenServices() throws Exception {
        // Where YourTokenServices extends DefaultTokenServices
        YourTokenServices tokenServices = new YourTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return tokenServices;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. You mean extend DefaultTokenServices in Resource Server or OAuth Server? Sorry for my stupid, how can i config to inject the custom TokenServices class?

Comment: In the auth server, as that i s the part doing the loading of the user details. I've added the implementation to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved reload problem this way.

```
@Bean
public ClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService() {
    return new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
}
```